# How to move tomcat logs file location

Tags: tomcat

I am running tomcat in my linux machine, is now i want to move the this default logs folder directory into some other location.

Like /usr/log

```
Please find the below logs view structure.
root@linux-vm:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.26/logs# ls -lrt

-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Dec 26 06:01 manager.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Dec 26 06:01 host-manager.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Dec 26 06:01 localhost_access_log.2019-12-26.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2481 Dec 26 06:12 localhost.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 31443 Dec 26 06:12 catalina.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1042803 Dec 26 06:24 catalina.out
```

Answer (score 1):

we have to configure two files in tomcat to move all the log files in one places.

```
vi server.xml

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="/root/user/logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

```
vi logging.properties

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /root/user/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /root/user/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /root/user/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /root/user/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
```

Finally restart the tomcat to reflect the above changes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `Tomcat` Log Locations as below:

**Linux:**

Locate the tomcat installed location: `<tomcat-base>/conf/logging.properties`

```
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

Finally you will need to change the `catalina.out`:

Locate the following code snippet in `Catalina.sh` script in bin directory of your tomcat base location and change the `CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out`
to:

`CATALINA_OUT=<add_location_you_prefer>/catalina.out`

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi
```